# Getting deprecated error even after disabling them

Tags: php, error-reporting

I've set this in my php script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
```

And yet when I run the code I get this:

```
Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in /home/www/prog/classes/inc.general.php on line 669
```

Why is this? The PHP site mentions that this should work:

```
// Report all errors except E_NOTICE
// This is the default value set in php.ini
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

Comment: Which version of PHP is running on the box? E_DEPRECATED wasn't introduced until V5.3

Comment: @Chet: He gets a `Deprecated`-error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

In development you should leave `E_DEPRECATED` enabled and fix your code instead. In production you should *disable* `E_NOTICE` too.

Also make sure there is nothing within your application, that may change your settings later during the execution.